# Jaspersoft Studio/Server Report - Preview in Studio is Working, Server is throwing an Error when executing

Tags: jasperserver

I recently tried to add more Reports to our Jasper Server to distribute them to those who need them.
This worked with the first Report I uploaded, but when trying to upload new ones, on trying to execute them through the Server I get an Error message.

The following is what I've extracted from the log:

2021-03-19T12:56:31,694 ERROR AsyncJasperPrintAccessor,pool-5-thread-9:321 - Error during report execution com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSSecurityException: Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. Wenden Sie sich an Ihren Systemadministrator. (6632)
Arguments:
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.validators.Validator.newSecurityException(Validator.java:544)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.validators.Validator.validateSQL(Validator.java:533)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:148)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1257)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:726)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDatasetRun.evaluate(JRFillDatasetRun.java:249)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementDataset.evaluateDatasetRun(JRFillElementDataset.java:259)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillCrosstab.evaluate(JRFillCrosstab.java:678)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:383)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:548)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummaryNoLastFooterSamePage(JRVerticalFiller.java:1238)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummary(JRVerticalFiller.java:1189)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportEnd(JRVerticalFiller.java:297)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:117)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:615)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:135)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousExecutor.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:956)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.startFill(BaseFillHandle.java:181)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$AsynchronousReportFiller.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:907)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1842)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runWithDataSource(EngineServiceImpl.java:1159)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1100)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:978)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

But since I am not using code to generate report I can't quite interpret the messages.

Can anybody tell me, why executing the report fails on the server, but is successful in the Jaspersoft Studio?

Both are running on the same Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT seems the developer handling this particular report started his queries with "which ..." which broke security rules set by Jaspersoft server by default, this has been changed, and reports do now properly generate when executed via the server